# Is "How beautiful are the flowers!" old-fasiond?

Tags: exclamatives

In Practical English Usage, Swan says

> Have you got a surprise coming!

and

> Was I mad!

are spoken American English and exclamations with ‘how’ or ‘what’ are old-fashioned, but I want to ask you if that really so because.. well, just other grammar books I have don’t mention these and I learned “How beautiful ~!” at a school, indeed that's a long time ago though..

Comment: Let's clear that up a bit, though I'm not 100% sure what entries and what edition of Swan's PEU you get the examples and explanations from. In my PEU, only "How ~!" is mentioned as "These are often felt to be a little formal and old-fashioned" (195.1), not "What ~!". As for American usage (under "exclamations"), I found only this note in 195.4, "Americans and some British speakers may use ordinary (non-negative) question forms in exclamations." (e.g. *Was I furious!*).

Comment: If my memory is correct it's 2005 edition. I will make sure of it later. I do remember I found it under "exclamations". There are 4 sentences. I didn't bother to type the 2 remaining sentences but I will type in them later.

Comment: OK. So it's under Inversion section of 'exclamations' I was reading, 302.2 is the number. It says "In spoken American English, exclamations often have the same form as ordinary (non-negative) questions." and gives the two sentences I've typed out up there. Then continues "In a rather old-fashioned literary style, inversion is sometimes found in exclamations after how and what.
- How beautiful are the flowers!
- What a peaceful place is Skegness!"
But now I see that I should have read the 195.1 to know he actually meant "How ~!" is the one old-fashioned. Ok. Thanks for giving me the hint.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, there are subtle differences between the two entries (195 and 302). In 302, it's about inversion, so the note "in a rather old-fashioned style" in 302.2 is only about "inversion found in exclamations after *how* and *what*", so *What a peaceful place is Skegness!* fits the case, but *What a peaceful place!* is not (because there is no inversion; the exclamation doesn't have even a verb). ...

Comment: ... Now, under 195, it's only 195.1 (exclamations about *how*) that Swan says "there are often felt to be a little formal or old-fashioned", with *how + subject + verb* as one of the pattern (e.g. *How you've grown!*)--note that there is no inversion like in 302.2, i.e. it's not *How (much) have you grown!*). In 195.2 (exclamations about *what*), Swan doesn't mention anything about formal or old-fashioned, and one of the examples he uses is *What a beautiful smile your sister has!* (still no inversion like 302.2).

Comment: Being a non-native speaker, I couldn't give you the right assertion. (For example, *How beautiful you are!* doesn't sound too old-fashioned for me, but it could sound very book-like for many native speakers, who might phrase it with something like *You're so beautiful!*.) But if you asked me about my idea, I think it would be something like this: in general, the shorter the exclamation is and the more plain the words are, the more relatively modern (i.e. not old-fashioned) it will feel like.

Comment: mm... This is more interesting than I thought. Thanks Damkerng T., again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete sentences which start with how or what do, in general, sound self-consciously poetic or old-fashioned, as in the case of your sentence. As always, in English, there are exceptions (don't you just hate it when that happens?). In general, these exceptions are technically incomplete sentences, and their informality counteracts the effect of the construction. Examples: "What an idiot", "How very good", "What a disaster!", or "How that takes me back".

In poetry, of course, sounding poetic is entirely acceptable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSQdRz-HlJw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3yCcXgbKrE

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for the links too. I am looking forward to get a great answer from someone rated this answer as a minus. :) By the way am I right to guess "How very good" is used in a cynical way?

Comment: Well, technically it's "ironic", but it may be cynical as well, depending on subject. Certainly you have the general idea.

Comment: +1 from me. I gradually came to see that it's something to do with the completion of the sentence with how or what that it feels like old or formal or self-consciously poetic.

Comment: "How I have longed for..." is a bit histrionic as well. "How long has it been?" seems pretty anodyne, though.

Comment: @Deipatrous - there was a famous Monty Python bit which starts with sailors adrift in a lifeboat, and the officer asks,, "How long is it, Mate?" followed by the response, "Don't you think that's a rather personal question, sir?"